# success_url from UpdateView to DetailView with pk in django

Tags: python, django

I make my own group permission page self with ListView to show Django Group list with a link to DetailView with pk and then give the change link to change the permissions with UpdateView.

I want to make the success_url of UpdateView to DetailView with pk, how to do this.

my code like:

*views.py*

```
class GroupCreation(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = 'add_group'
    model = Group
    form_class = GroupCreateModelForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:group_list')
    template_name = 'accounts/groups/group_creation.html'


class GroupsListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    permission_required = 'view_group'
    allow_empty = True
    model = Group
    ordering = 'name'
    template_name = 'accounts/groups/groups_list.html'
    form = GroupCreateModelForm
    extra_context = {'form': form, }


class GroupDetailView(PermissionRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    permission_required = 'view_group'
    model = Group
    template_name = 'accounts/groups/group_detail.html'


class GroupUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'change_group'
    model = Group
    fields = ('permissions',)
    template_name = 'accounts/groups/group_update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('account:group_detail')
```

*urls.py*

```
path('groups/', views.GroupsListView.as_view(), name='group_list'),
path('groups/<int:pk>/', views.GroupDetailView.as_view(), name='group_detail'),
path('groups/<int:pk>/change/', views.GroupUpdateView.as_view(), name='group_change'),
path('groups/create/', views.GroupCreation.as_view(), name='group_creation'),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `get_success_url` method in your `UpdateView` instead of `success_url` attribute; This way you can access the edited object's `pk`:

```
def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('account:group_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```